# updating multiple lines without making a new line python

Tags: python-3.x, linux

```py
import requests
import json
from time import sleep
import sys
try:
    while True:
        sleep(2)

        response = requests.get("https://api.binance.us/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=DOGEUSD")
        output = response.json()
        data = json.dumps(output['price'])
        punctuation = '''"'''
        remove_punct = ""
        for character in data:
            if character not in punctuation:
                remove_punct = remove_punct + character
        
        doge_ammout = float(805.77685148)
        price = remove_punct
        price_as_float = float(price)
        net_profit = str(price_as_float * doge_ammout)


        print('current price of doge: '+ price, flush = True)
        print('how much doge you have: ' + net_profit + '\r', flush = True)
        sys.stdout.flush()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    exit('\n')
```

i want there to be two lines without it making a new line every update
every time it runs it either makes a new pair of lines or combines the strings together or overwriting the string

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve].  As is, it is hard to figure out what you are trying to do.

Comment: Why are you looping over the JSON instead of the price?

Comment: Why not just `price_as_float = float(output['price'])`?

Comment: its looping because it needs to get current price of doge coin